# Compare two values in pandas dataframe and if they are equal add it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am having a dataframe and while grouping on it, I get the below result set.

```
Name | Score | Salary A | SALARY B
ABC  | 20    | 300      | 500
XYZ  | 30    | 400      | 600
PQR  | 40    | 300      | 500
TFW  | 50    | 0        | 0
OIP  | 60    | 0        | 0
QWE  | 50    | None     | None
UYT  | 40    | None     | None
```

I need to compare the salaryA and salaryB values(salaryA v/s salaryA and salaryB v/s salaryB). If Salary is the same then I want to SUM the score else I have to take MAX of the score.

**Expected output**

```
Name     | Score
ABC, PQR | 60
XYZ      | 30
TFW      | 50
OIP      | 60
QWE      | 50
UYT      | 40
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Dan Added expected output

Comment: I don't quite understand the logic, what happens if the `Salary A` for two `Name`s are the same but `Salary B` is different? would you want the `max` for this? e.g. if `PQR`, `Salary B` was 400

Comment: @Dan yes. Max in that case.

Comment: How does max play a part here? if values doesn't match in a group, sum of the group returns the max automatically.. ?

Comment: yeah, sum or max it is the same when there is no match.

Comment: right,match based on only Sal A and Sal B or even the Name play a part? if Name play a part how does ABC and PQR match

Comment: @anky_91 I don't see your answer anymore

Comment: @Knot I have deleted it as I was not sure how to proceed with this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
a = pd.read_csv('yourdata.dat',sep='|')
a['total'] = a.iloc[:,2] + a.iloc[:,3]
a.groupby('total').agg({'Name ':','.join,' Score ':'sum'}).reset_index()[['Name ',' Score ']]


         Name    Score 
0  ABC  ,PQR         60
1        XYZ         30
```